# Random number generating over the specified range in an array

Tags: c

I am messing with arrays for the first time and I'm trying to make the code generate a number in between 55 and 99, which for the most part it does. But occasionally I get some completely wild or random number that is either way bigger or way smaller (ie 32456 or -21578).

```
int main()
{
srand(time(0));

int tS;
int testScores[tS];

    for(tS=0; tS<200; ++tS)
    {
    testScores[tS]=rand() % (99 - 55 + 1) + 55;
    printf("%i \n", testScores[tS]);
    }

}
```

Can somebody explain as to why this is happening or how to correct it? Like I said, it works fine most of the time, but if I run it a few times over at least one or two will have a random number well outside of the specified numbers.

Comment: You never initialized `tS`, so what do you expect the size of the array to be?

Comment: Hint: Your array is initialized with an uninitialized size. It's a junk array at that point, you can't use it. Consider making a `MAX_SIZE = 200` definition of some sort.

Comment: So I changed int testScores[tS] to int testScores[200]
I appreciate the hint @tadman.
When you talk about the max size I am assuming you are talking about the array size correct?

Comment: Yes. It's generally a good practice to avoid *magical* numbers like `200` showing up randomly in your code. Either `#define` or `const` your parameters so it's obvious what they are, and what implications there are for changing them. Having something like `SCORE_LENGTH` makes it easy to use in all the places that need that, so if you ever change it, everything should work out.

Comment: You may be interested by _cavets_ at [c-faq Q13.16](https://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to conflate your loop variable `tS` with the *uninitialized* size of the array.  For the latter, you should prefer using a symbolic constant `N`so it can be allocated at compile time (opposed to a VLA).  I also added the missing headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 200
#define MIN 55
#define MAX 99

int main(void) {
    srand(time(0));
    int testScores[N];
    for(int tS=0; tS<N; ++tS) {
        testScores[tS]=rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1) + MIN;
        printf("%i \n", testScores[tS]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, I appreciate you typing out the code for me. tadman had explained it in a way I was able to fix. This is a bit off topic but is there a way for me to use the array outside of the for loop? I tried a printf of it outside the for loop and it prints 0, but that makes it difficult for me to use it anywhere except inside of that loop.